# WPF Toolkit Accordion - How To Data Bind

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit, accordion

I have been trying (and failing) to dynamically create an accordion using databinding.

I have a collection called MenuGroups, which contains a string 'ModuleName' and an IList collection called MenuItems. I wish to bind the MenuGroups to the headers and the MenuItems to the content.

The closest I have managed so far uses this XAML:

```
<WPFToolkit:Accordion ItemsSource="{Binding MenuGroups}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="OneOrMore">
    <WPFToolkit:Accordion.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ModuleName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
     </WPFToolkit:Accordion.ItemTemplate>

     <WPFToolkit:Accordion.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding MenuItems/MenuItemName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
     </WPFToolkit:Accordion.ContentTemplate>
</WPFToolkit:Accordion>
```

This produces the headers correctly, but only the first menu item in each group is displayed in the content. I have tried various different connotations of the above, but as yet I have not achieved the desired result. I tried a ListView instead of a TextBlock in the content template thinking I would need that for multiple items,but that produced a blank content area.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

The `/` character in a property path means bind to the *current* item in a collection.  Since you aren't setting the current item in some other way, it will always just be the first item.  See [PropertyPath XAML Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx).

If you want the content to be the entire list of MenuItems, you should use an [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx), or one of its subclasses such as [`ListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.aspx).

Something like this will give you a text box for every MenuItem in the collection:

```
<WPFToolkit:Accordion.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding MenuItemName}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</WPFToolkit:Accordion.ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for your reply. As I said in my original post I did try a listbox without success. I am now using a different data structure and for whatever reason this has resolved my problem.